# Editing Bar Buttons with PushSegue iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I want to have barButtonItems in the navigation bar of a view which I arrive at through a pushSegue.

I tried to achieve this by adding a navigation bar item to my storyboard, but when I launch the app, the barButton doesn't show in the build. See the screenshots here:

**How the navigation bar looks on build**

[image: How the navigation bar looks on build]

**How I built it in Storyboards**

[image: How I built it in Storyboards]

**Flow of the Storyboard**

[image: Flow of the Storyboard]

I segue to my MainTextView by clicking on a cell using this code:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)
        if let destination = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"MainTextView") as? MainTextView {
            destination.post = (posts[indexPath.row])
            destination.delegate = self
            navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
        }
    } 

}
```

The back button doesn't even show up in the Storyboard. How could I change the default back button and add additional buttons to the navigation bar programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this might be a Xcode 11/ios 13 related issue. Click on the segue and change it from push to present modally. From there change presentation context to fullscreen. You might be able to leave the it as push but when you click on your your viewcontroller/navigation controller go to the attributes inspector and look for a option called presentation, and set it to full screen.

Another option to try is to click on the view controllers, go to attributes inspector and under navigation controller - bar visibility tap (shows navigation bar)

Last thing I can think of is that when your segue to and from should be connected to the navigation controller.

Actually a few more possibilities... 
1) check your debug view hierarchy when you launch the app. What I mean by this is

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html

basically its a button you click and you'll be able to see how the views are stacked onto of each other. My best guess is that while you have a bar item button there, the nested button is not actually present/showing.

2) nest your tableviewcontroller in another navigation controller.